# installing ubuntu 10.4 on asus 1005pe

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, asus

I am planning to get a couple of ASUS 1005PE netbook's for our group project and I want to install Ubuntu on them.
I have been reading on the net and found that there were some issues with drivers and button's and all and work arounds for the same.

My question is, has the latest version of Ubuntu resolved all these so that it will work out of the box? Has anyone done this already?

Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears almost everything work out of the box, except:

- LCD brightness adjustment you will need to add "acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor" options in the boot command line. Add it to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in **/etc/default/grub** or see [bug #512567](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/512567).
- The Wi-Fi enable/disable hotkey (Fn-F2) disables both on Wi-Fi and wired Ethernet (see [Bug #557048](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/557048)).
- While the stereo microphones work with Ubuntu in general, they do not work with Skype. The two steps to resolve this issue are to first, go into alsamixer and set either the Left or Right microphone channel to a very high number (I set mine at around 90) and the other at zero (0). Second, after launching Skype, go into the Options settings and select Sound Devices. Uncheck the box labeled "Allow Skype to automatically adjust my mixer level". Doing the first will actually fix the problem with Skype. Doing the second will make sure Skype doesn't reset the levels back to their defaults.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks#Asus%20Eee%20PC%201005PE